# Why symbol is not equal to symbol

Tags: ruby

I did:

```
x = :foo, y = %q{foo}.to_sym, x.==(y)
# => [:foo, :foo, false]
```

I am wondering why `:foo` is not equal to `:foo`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parallel assignment works differently in Ruby, and if you want multiple statements on one line, you need to separate them with semicolons (not commas).

The statement you executed:

```rb
x = :foo, y = %q{foo}.to_sym, x == y
```

Is equivalent to:

```rb
x = [:foo, y = %q{foo}.to_sym, x == y]
```

N.B. `x` is not yet defined when the right-hand side of the expression is evaluated, so the last term is effectively comparing `nil` and `:foo`. The `y` assignment also happens while the right-hand side of the expression is evaluating, and the result gets included in the array literal being assigned to `x`.

Here's what you meant to do:

```rb
x, y = :foo, %q{foo}.to_sym; x == y # => true
```

Just an aside, `x.==(y)` works because `:==` is technically a method, but in idiomatic Ruby you just write `x == y`. The interpreter knows what you mean.

Comment: Got it.Thank you so much!

Comment: Nicely explained!

Comment: Nice answer, but there is a logical leap from "`x` is not yet defined" to "the last term is effectively comparing `nil` and `:foo`.", in particular, why an undefined variable is evaluated as `nil` is unexplained.

Comment: And the reason why it doesn't raise the exception *"NameError (undefined local variable or method \`x' for ...)"* can be found [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods) (assuming it wasn't defined before).

Answer (score 2):

> Nice answer, but there is a logical leap from "x is not yet defined" to "the last term is effectively comparing nil and :foo.", in particular, why an undefined variable is evaluated as nil is unexplained.

This has to do with how variable hoisting is implemented in Ruby. It's an obnoxious feature of JavaScript too.